# SQL: Join table a and b then join table c to get the results that are on a but not on c?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have 3 tables.  Table a pk = userid, table b and c fk = userid.  On table b RoleID column is equal to Usermanager column from table c but w a new value.

So i joined table a and b with below query

```
select a.Username, a.Userid, b.Roleid
from NewTable a
join RoleTable b
    on a.UserID=b.UserID
where b.RoleID = 2
```

This results in 502 records.

Table c query is

```
select *
from OldTable
where UserManager = 1
    and Authorized = 1
    and Status = 'A'
```

This results in 500 records.

So I'm trying to join the 2 queries to find the 2 records that are not on table c but are only on table a.

Thanks.

Comment: Select * from A where userid not in (select userid from C)

Comment: a Left Join should get you records that are only in Table A and not in Table C. The logic goes:-

select * from Table A LEFT JOIN Table C C ON A.Key = C.Key
Where C.Key is NULL

Comment: `not in` is intuitive, but slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.Username, a.Userid, b.Roleid 
from NewTable a 
join RoleTable b 
on a.UserID=b.UserID 
where 
    b.RoleID = 2
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
        (select * 
        from OldTable AS c
        where c.UserManager = 1 
            and 
            c.Authorized = 1 
            and 
            c.Status = 'A'
            AND
            a.userid = c.userid)
```

I used the two queries you mentioned you were using and just made the table c query into a WHERE NOT EXISTS subquery.  It should provide those 2 results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Left Join

```
select subA.*
from (
    select a.Username, a.Userid, b.Roleid
    from NewTable a
    join RoleTable b
        on a.UserID=b.UserID
    where b.RoleID = 2
) subA
left join (
    select userID
    from OldTable
    where UserManager = 1
        and Authorized = 1
        and Status = 'A'
) subB
on subA.Userid = subB.UserID
Where subB.userid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.  You can work out the details for your database.

```
select fields
from tableA join tableB on something
where whatever
and tableA.someField in 
(select someField
from tableA join tableB on something
where whatever

except 
select someEquivalentField
from tableC)
```

The two `where whatevers` should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly... the following will join Table A and Table C and then find those that dont have corresponding values in Table C

```
Select * from Table A A
LEFT JOIN Table C C On A.UserId = C.UserId
Where C.UserId is NULL
```

This is the basic concept.. you need to work on it to get the syntax to fit your motives